# Why a child window may not receive mouse events?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, wtl

I have a custom WTL control which is a panel with a list and a custom scroll bar.

```
class Panel
: public ATL::CWindowImpl<Panel>, public WTL::CDoubleBufferImpl<Panel> {
public:
    DECLARE_WND_CLASS("Panel")

    BEGIN_MSG_MAP_EX(Panel)
        MSG_WM_CREATE(OnCreate)
        MSG_WM_DESTROY(OnDestroy)
        MSG_WM_SIZE(OnSize)
        CHAIN_MSG_MAP(CDoubleBufferImpl<Panel>)
        REFLECT_NOTIFICATIONS()
    END_MSG_MAP()
```

The scroll bar is created by the panel in OnCreate():

```
m_scrollBar.Create(m_hWnd, WTL::CRect(...));
```

That scroll bar works fine in many other dialog windows. However, inside that panel control the scroll bar appears, but receives no mouse events at all. If I add `WM_MOUSEMOVE` handler to the panel, it does get called.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Could the parent control be swalling all windows messages for that region?

Comment: No. The list does recieve the mouse events. The scroll bar class was the problem. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. The problem was in the scroll bar class declaration:

```
class CScrollBase : public ATL::CWindowImpl<CScrollBase, WTL::CStatic>
```

Changing to:

```
class CScrollBase : public ATL::CWindowImpl<CScrollBase>
```

makes the scroll bar work on the panel.

Answer (score 2):

A good way to diagnose problems with Windows messaging is to use Spy++ or [Winspector](http://www.windows-spy.com/) which allow you to get an under-the-covers look at Windows messaging.